# Oracle vs Oracle ODBC

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, odbc

The following code works fine from within Oracle's SqlPlus (using Oracle 11.2.02.0g) however when I connect with and ODBC connection via C# code, I get told I have an invalid character.

Since the single quote didn't work in SQLplus, I'm assuming the characters that are consider invalid by ODBC are the double quotes. I've tried braces '{' and brackets '[' but still get the same error  -> ERROR [HY000][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00911:invalid character <-

Any help would be much appreciated. I still don't understand why SQL statements would be interpreted differently because of the connection type.

```
CREATE USER "AD1\EGRYXU" IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;
```

Error if ran alone that states the username conflicts with another user or role name. It does create the user in the database.

C# Code is below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string happy = "";
            string sql1 = "";
            string sql2 = "";
            string sql3 = "";
            string sql4 = "";
            string column;
            int rownum = -1;
            bool frst = false;
            string dirIni = "\\\\ramxtxss021-f01\\hou_common_013\\globaluser\\";
            string fileIni = "add_users.sql";
            string transIniFullFileName = Path.Combine(dirIni, fileIni);
            System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();

            num_users = (usrdetails.Count > 0);
            if (regions && num_users)
            {
               using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(transIniFullFileName))
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < usrdetails.Count; y++)
                    {
                        switch(usrdetails[y].add_del.ToUpper())
                        {
                            case "A":
                                  sql1 = "CREATE USER \"" + usrdetails[y].userID.ToUpper() + "\" IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;";
                                  sql2 = "GRANT EDMROLE TO \"" + usrdetails[y].userID.ToUpper() + "\";";
                                  sql3 = "INSERT INTO MD_SITE_USER VALUES(generate_key(5), (select user_id from MD_SITE_USER where user_name = '" +
                                         usrdetails[y].group + "') , {" + usrdetails[y].userID.ToUpper() + "}, " + usrdetails[y].seclev +
                                         ", '" + usrdetails[y].username.ToUpper() + "', 'U', '" + usrdetails[y].isext.ToUpper() + "', 'N');";
                                  sw.WriteLine(sql1);
                                  sw.WriteLine(sql2);
                                  sw.WriteLine(sql3);
                                  break;
                            case "D":
                                  sql2 = "DELETE MD_SITE_APP_ACTION_OWNER WHERE user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM MD_SITE_USER where user_name  = ‘"+ usrdetails[y].userID + "’+ and user_or_group = ‘U’);";
                                  sql3 = "DELETE FROM MD_SITE_USER where user_name  = ‘"+ usrdetails[y].userID + "’ and user_or_group = ‘U’;";
                                  sql4 = "DROP USER "+ usrdetails[y].userID + " FROM USERS;";
                                  sw.WriteLine(sql2);
                                  sw.WriteLine(sql3);
                                  sw.WriteLine(sql4);
                                  break;
                            default:
                                  MessageBox.Show("Add/Delete command argument not recognized for user\r\n" + usrdetails[y].userID + " \r\n Argument -> " + usrdetails[y].add_del);
                                  break;

                        }
                    }
                 sw.Close();
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < region.Count; x++)
                {
                    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};" +
                                            "Dbq=" + region[x].dbname +
                                            ";Uid=" + region[x].username + ";Pwd=" + region[x].password + ";";
                    try
                    {
                        string cmdTexts = File.ReadAllText(transIniFullFileName);
                        conn.Open();
                        using (conn)
                        {
                            command.Connection = conn;
                            command.CommandText = cmdTexts;
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                            Form6.dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                            if (!frst)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                                {
                                    column = dr.GetName(i);
                                    Form6.dataGridView2.Columns.Add("col" + i, column);
                                    Form6.dataGridView2.Columns[i].FillWeight = 1;
                                }
                                frst = true;
                            }
                            rownum++;
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                            dataGridView1.Rows[rownum].Cells[0].Value = "Results for Region -> " + Form5.region[x].dbname;
                            dataGridView1.Refresh();
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                rownum++;
                                Form6.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                                for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                                {
                                    column = dr.GetValue(i).ToString();
                                    Form6.dataGridView2.Rows[rownum].Cells[i].Value = column;
                                }
                            }
                            Form6.dataGridView2.Refresh();
                            Form6.dataGridView2.Show();
                            Form6.Show();
                        }
                       conn.Close();
                       Form6.dataGridView2.Refresh();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!regions)
                    happy = "Error - You have not selected any regions.\r\n";
                else
                    happy = "Regions are now selected.\r\n";
                if (!num_users)
                    happy = happy + "Error - You have not entered any users.\r\n";
                MessageBox.Show(happy);
            }
          File.Delete(transIniFullFileName);
        }
```

Comment: You may want to show us your C# code...

Comment: There are three separate statements here.  Which of the three is causing an error when executed from C#?

Comment: As far as I know the 1st and 2nd statements (3rd is dependent on the first 2). C# code is now included as well.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to send three separate SQL statements in one call to the database.  I doubt that is going to work, particularly not when you're combining DML and DDL.  What happens if you make three separate database calls, one per statement?  I'd also strongly suggest that you use bind variables in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Okay. I changed it to just one statement, however if you look below the statement, you can see I still get and error. But it does create the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ";" (semi-colon) in the command text..

The command text within ODBC or ODP should be a command, e.g. not a set of commands, therefore - ";" is not relevant, and is an invalid character.

---

it appears you are trying to run a script.. 
if that is your intent, it should be padded with a "begin" and "end" for the code to be able to run:

```
BEGIN
 INSERT...;
 DELETE ...;
END;
```

(refer to http://www.intertech.com/Blog/executing-sql-scripts-with-oracle-odp/ for more info)

Last thing - if you want to run a "create user" (or any other DDL) from within an anonymous block or a procedure you need to run it with "execute immediate" syntax:

```
BEGIN
 execute immediate 'CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY';
END;
```